# Why does perl 5.x matches an underscore with [0-9a-zA-Z]?

Tags: regex, perl

In the following code:

```
my $s="_";  
if ( $s =~ /[0-9a-zA-z]/  ) {
      print " $s contains [0-9a-zA-z] \n";
}
```

I'm getting as result

```
 _ contains [0-9a-zA-z]
```

Why is underscore considered as part of this character class?

I've tried with both 5.8.8 and 5.16.3 (on 64bit RHEL 6.8/7.3 respectively)

Comment: Because the `[A-z]` range matches it.

Comment: In other words, you have a typo: what you want is `[0-9a-zA-Z]`. The second `Z` must be uppercase. Ironically, you wrote it correctly in the question's title.

Comment: got it . It was meant to be [0-9a-zA-Z] but I mistype the second z as lowercase. Thank you so much!!!